# Input String in a Java Game

Tags: java, string, swing, input, jframe

I am looking for a way to implement some kind of an input.
My game is simple. I have a game loop with tick and render methods.
I am using JFrame and Canvas and have my game separated into a few GameStates
I want when the game start to enter into a GameState where the user can write
 
his/her name/username so that I can store it and use it for different stuff in the game.

Here is a simplified example of my Game:

Game Loop:

```
public void run() {
    initialize();
    while (running) {
            tick();
            render();
    }
}

private void tick() {
    if (StateManager.getCurrentState() != null) {
        StateManager.getCurrentState().tick();
    }
}

private void render() {
    Display.clearScreen();

    if (StateManager.getCurrentState() != null) {
        StateManager.getCurrentState().render(graphics);
    }

    graphics.dispose();
    bufferStrategy.show();
}
```

Every Game State has it's own tick and render method.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can think of a method with my keyManager. But I am almost 100% sure that is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: When using JFrame, couldn't you just show a textfield or a JOptionPane popup ?

Comment: It will be best if it is not in a separate window.

Comment: `It will be best if it is not in a separate window` - why? that is the way it is usually don't! If you don't want it in a separate window then you need to add a JTextField to the game panel.

Comment: Can you show me how it is done. With the JTextField

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for working examples.